# Create Python DataFrame with the same column values from other DataFrames

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, unique, dataframe

I have many python DataFrames and I would like each of these DataFrames to have the same values in on column. How I can do this?

Example:

- DataFrame_1 has a column with characters A,B,V,D
- DataFrame_2 has a column with characters D,C,B
- DataFrame_3 has a column with char A,B

How I can return a dataframe with characters B,B,B (because B is in all dataframes)

Comment: Can you please clarify the columns.  Are the letters A, B, C, etc. the names of the columns, or are they values in the column's data?  If the latter, what are the names of the columns in the three dataframes?  Are they all the same?

Comment: The A,B,C letters are values in the columns. Same name of the columns in the three dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

One convoluted method would be to use multiple nested calls to [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
In [39]:

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','B','V','D']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['D','C','B']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','B']})
df[df.a.isin(df1[df1.a.isin(df2.a)].a)]
Out[39]:
   a
1  B
```

Another method would be to call [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), this assumes the values are unique:

```
In [46]:

np.intersect1d(df2.a.unique(), np.intersect1d(df.a.unique(), df1.a.unique()))
Out[46]:
array(['B'], dtype=object)
```

Again we could perform 2 inner [merges](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) this would merge on the values that exist in all dfs:

```
In [47]:

df.merge(df1, on='a').merge(df2, on='a')
Out[47]:
   a
0  B
```

**timings**

```
In [48]:

%timeit df[df.a.isin(df1[df1.a.isin(df2.a)].a)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop
In [49]:

%timeit np.intersect1d(df2.a.unique(), np.intersect1d(df.a.unique(), df1.a.unique()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 360 µs per loop
In [50]:

%timeit df.merge(df1, on='a').merge(df2, on='a')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.76 ms per loop
```

the numpy method wins easily on this dataset

Answer (score 0):

How about treating each column as a set and then taking the intersection:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'V', 'D'], 
                   'col2': ['D', 'C', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'col3': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

# First df column is a set
new_set = set(df.iloc[:, 0])  
# Iterate through remaining columns in df, taking intersection
for col in df.iloc[:, 1:]:
    new_set = set(df[col]).intersection(new_set)
```

The convert the set back to a dataframe or series:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([new_set])
print(new_df)
   0
0  B
```

Comment: A set type `set` - has been a builtin since Python 2.4, deprecated since 2.6 and remove in 3.x+... So unless the OP is using Python 2.3 using the `sets` module is discouraged.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.9 and the above code worked fine.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: It will... but like I said - it's not recommended... just `new_set = set(df.iloc[:, 0])` would be fine for instance...

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll amend my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

To get unique values that are present across all three DF's, you can use:

```
unique_vals = set(df1['col']).intersection(df2['col'], df3['col'])
```

Which will (unsurprisingly) give you a `set`, which you can then put back into a DF/Series as you wish.